# Discrete Kalman Filter

Tags: kalman-filter

I have this state equations for Discrete Kalman Filter:

1) $x_{k+1}=Ax_{k}+Bu_{k}+Gw_{k}$

2) $y_{k}=Cx_{k}+v_{k}$

I don't understand/know what is $G$ in 1).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A lot of textbooks define $w_{k}$ as white noise, where $w_{k}$ may or may not be a vector. The $G$ then is the matrix that modifies the variance of the noise $w_{k}$, and is assumed to be known. Note that in a Kalman filter, the noise going into the system (is this case , $w_{k}$) is assumed unknown, only its characteristics are known, one of which is $G$.

Maybe useful information: If $w_{k}$ is a zero mean Gaussian white noise signal with unit variance, then $\sqrt{G}w_{k}$ is a white noise signal with variance $G$.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes $G=B$, when there is actuation noise. Eg. $u$ is motor torque command from the controller. But the actual motor torque may be $u+\Delta u$, where the uncertainty of $\Delta u$ can be described by $w$.